# How do I view the job queue in lftp after it has moved to a background process?

Tags: ssh, ftp

I've just started using lftp for remote transferring files on my Raspberry Pi running Debian. I know how to transfer the files, and use `queue` and `jobs` to add and view transferring files.

However, I'm not actually sure on how to view these transfers once lftp moves to the background. [The lftp man page](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) mentions how lftp is moving to the background, but when I open a new instance of the program from shell and type `jobs`, the queue is empty. However, I can clearly see using my file manager that the transfers are still happening, as the files are there and growing in size.

I'm guessing that when I reopen lftp, it's just opening a new instance that isn't connected to the `nohup` mode lftp that has the active queue. I've tried searching various places, but no one else seems to have this particular issue.

So, I guess what I'm asking is twofold:

1. Is there a way to easily attach to the background lftp process to view the current `jobs` list?
2. If not, is there a way to view this at all?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are correct that instances of lftp do not share the job queue, which is of course similar to how shell job queue works.

Still, lftp can indeed attach to an existing backgrounded session. According to [lftp news](http://lftp.yar.ru/news.html) version history, the feature was introduced in version 4.3.0 (2011-06-17). If your connection to lftp session disconnects or you exit with backgrounded transfers ongoing, with recent versions you can still resume the backgrounded lftp process and get access to its job queue.

From lftp man page:

> **attach**  [*PID*]
>
> Attach the terminal to specified backgrounded lftp process.

To do this you need to know the process id, PID, of the backgrounded lftp process. A simple way to do this is the pgrep command, which lists matching process IDs.

For example, here I background a transfer in lftp:

```
lftp remote:/path> get oi-dev-151a-x86.iso 
[0] get oi-dev-151a-x86.iso &                                             
     `oi-dev-151a-x86.iso' at 655360 (0%) 296.1K/s eta:46m [Receiving data]
lftp remote:/path> exit
[82106] Moving to background to complete transfers...
```

This lists the pid needed to attach, but in case we did not have this noted down, we can find it again with pgrep:

```
$ pgrep lftp
82106
```

And here we resume the backgrounded lftp:

```
$ lftp
lftp :~> attach 82106
[82106] Attached to terminal.
lftp remote:/path> jobs
[0] get oi-dev-151a-x86.iso 
    `oi-dev-151a-x86.iso' at 42827776 (5%) 1.49M/s eta:10m [Receiving data]
```

The Debian stable version might not have the attach feature though, but you can still list the active lftp processes with pgrep.

Comment: This is absolutely correct, though I'm very late commenting on that fact. Thank you very much. For those that come along later, pgrep actually did not work for me. I had to use "ps aux | grep lftp", as (for some reason) pgrep would sometimes not return a value when lftp was certainly running and found with ps aux.

Comment: If parallel chunk downloads were initiated aka `pget`, then you can simply cat the file it generates (stored next to the actual file) to see the seek positions. Not very helpful, but gives you an indication.

Answer (score 1):

From the [lftp man page](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html):

```
If  you exit lftp when some jobs are not finished yet, lftp will move itself to
nohup mode in background. The same happens when you have a real modem hangup or
when you close an xterm.
```

You cannot connect to background processes running with nohup if the parent process has terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Collected from the lftp man page:
Use `ctrl-z` to move the process in background and exit `lftp`,
later start lftp again and type `wait`.

Comment: As mentioned above, if you exit lftp, it is possible to find PID of the running lftp process (`pgrep lftp`), then run `lftp` again, then do `attach <PID>`, then `wait` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I am on stable Debian.

After my computer entered sleep mode, I started it again and I had to reconnect to ssh, then I navigated to the local dir with cd, then login to external server via lfpt and go to remote dir and run the same command I used from the start to initiate the mirroring.

mirror -c --parallel=10

This resumed the previous transfer.

I am still mad at myself for not running it in screen from the start. That is what I would recommend to anyone else. Run all shit like this in screen so you don't have to worry about being disconnected etc.