# How do I attach running lftp process

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, lftp

I have `lftp` process running for days at a time on a CentOS machine. I read the `lftp` man pages and discovered the `attach` command. However when I call it with the respective process id from the `lftp` shell I get `Unknown command "attach".`

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear what it is you're actually trying to do. What do you mean by "attach" exactly?

Comment: What i mean is to be able to view the current jobs progress/output or job queue in the terminal

Comment: And where is that output going currently? How was the process created?

Answer (score 1):

There could be a few reasons:

1. Your `lftp` version is lower than 4.3.0, see [Changes](http://lftp.yar.ru/news.html).
2. You're using Debian stable version.

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/528669/526734):

> The Debian stable version might not have the attach feature though, but you can still list the active lftp processes with pgrep.

But you can trick the shell if you set `cmd:move-background-detach` setting to `false` and use the `fg` command to bring `lftp` back. *See [man page](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html).*

Answer (score 0):

On stable Debian.

After being disconnected (computer entered sleep mode) I simply reconnected in ssh, cd to the local dir, logged in to external server via lftp and did same command again

mirror -c --parallel=10

And it resumed